# koa's redirect function doesn't work well

Tags: node.js, redirect, koa, koa2, koa-router

when I use `ctx.redirect`, koa just sends GET request but not actually redirect the tab to other page from where It was. I'm just trying to redirect to user's page after signup. Here's code.

**signup**

```
router.post('/signup', async (ctx, next) => {
    let data = ctx.request.body
    const param = await makeParam(data)

    try {
        const user = new User(param)
        await user.save()
        ctx.redirect(`/u/${data.username}`)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Failed to save post request", e, param)
    }
})
```

and here's the router for userpage

```
router.get('/:userName', async (ctx, next) => {
    let userName = ctx.params.userName

    let renderData = {
        userName: userName,
        profilePic: "",
        itemCount: "",
        contentCount: "",
        joinedDate: "",
        lastVisited: ""
    }

    await ctx.render('form/form4', renderData)
})
```